# About norm and inverse operator $Af(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, inverse-function

---

Problem :

Let $E=\left(\mathcal{C}[0,1],\|.\|_{\infty}\right)$

Defined operator $A$ :

$$A ~~:E\to~~E$$
$$Af(x)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$

1. Prove that $\|A\|=1$

Then $A^{-1}$ existed , is bounded??

---

My attempts:

I was find $\|A\|\leq 1$

For $f≡1$ then $\|f\|_{\infty}=1$

But I can't get $\|Af\|_{\infty}=1$

The second question I need to prove $A$ are invective so ,

$Af(x)=0\implies \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=0$

$\implies f(t)=0 $

by derivative both side is this correct??

And what about bounded of $A^{-1}$

Comment: $Af(x)=x$ when $f \equiv 1$. What is the sup norm of the identity function? $Af$ is always continuously differentiable, so $A$ is not surjective.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so the norm equal? I don't understand $A^{-1}$ doesn't existe ??

Comment: Besides $(Af)(0)=0,$ so $A$ is not surjective, as nonzero constant functions do not belong to the range of $A.$ The inverse operator is well defined on the range of $A.$ But it is unbounded, since $A^{-1}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sir range($A$) here is ?

Comment: Call me Ryszard. The range consists of all functions $g$  such that $g'$ is continuous and $g(0)=0.$ The inverse operator (defined on the range) is $A^{-1}g=g'.$